# Numpy.dot on multiple pairs of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector, numpy-ndarray

I have two lists of matrices [numpy.ndarray]: (a1,a2,a3.....,an) and (b1,b2,b3......,bn) each one is a square matrix of **some** size, not all a matrices are the same size and not all b matrices are the same size, but it is guaranteed that dim(a[i])==dim(b[i]) (which means we are only multiplying matrices of same size).

i want to dot product them respectively: a1*b1,a2*b2.....an*bn and store the results in say c1,c2....etc
is there any way to do it besides going over the pairs 1 by 1 in a for loop?

im currently using:

```
# a_list and b_list contain n matrices each
# a[i] & b[i] are numpy.ndarray objects
a_list = [a1,a2,.....]
b_list = [b1,b2,.....]
result_list = []
for i in range(n):
    result_list.append(numpy.dot(a_list[i],b_list[i])
```

Comment: Is there any way you can group the matrices by size? Short answer is "no" though.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, i will do some testing now with ec2604's solution and see how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the accepted solution is syntactic sugar for a for loop, however we can look for a more interesting option here.

Technically what we want is a numpy array of numpy arrays, allowing us to do vectorized operations between them, similar to how np.array([1,2,3]) * np.array([3,4,5]) performs scalar multiplication between each element.

So we'd like a numpy array of numpy arrays, except that we'd like the * operator to be defined as matrix multiplication instead of element-wise multiplication. It's interesting to note that this is the case for the np.matrix class. It is however ***important to note that this class is deprecated and can cause complications***, but for the case of learning / understanding things all the way, we can try using this class..

```
import nummpy as np
b_0 = np.asmatrix(np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3))

# b_0 = 0 1 2
#       3 4 5
#       6 7 8

b_1 = np.asmatrix(np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2))

# b_1 = 0 1
#       2 3   

a_0 = np.asmatrix(np.eye(3))
a_1 = np.asmatrix(np.eye(2))
a = np.asarray([a_0, a_1])
b = np.asarray([b_0, b_1])
a * b # We get [b_0, b_1])
```

If this were an important syntactic option for you, you could perhaps write a custom class that would be compatible with numpy arrays (and thus not use np.matrix). This will probably however be slightly slower than using a plain old for loop with np.dot.

Comment: THIS! this is what i needed (not to take anything away from the other solution), ill get right to work on writing a class, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You can use python list comprehensions:

```
result_list = [a.dot(b) for a, b in zip(a_list, b_list)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Its a bit more compact like this

Comment: @Tomfus it's also likely marginally faster